How to read attached object data of points in dxf?
I reading a dxf with ezdxf module in python
some entities have Attribute data, xdata and object data
i able read attribute and xdata how to read the attribute data?

dwg = ezdxf.readfile(file)
for layer in dwg.layers:
    entities_on_layer = dwg.modelspace().query( f'INSERT[layer=="{layer.dxf.name}"]')
    # print(layer.dxf.name,len(entities_on_layer))
    for entity in entities_on_layer:
        print(entity.Xdata.data)
        print(entity.attribs)


Maybe it's a good idea to read the docs: https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I read the  documentation but didn't find any information about 'object data'.

These are called BLOCK attributes, and here is a tutorial about BLOCKs: https://ezdxf.mozman.at/docs/tutorials/blocks.html#block-attributes

Block attributes and object data are different. Block attributes are only for block entities, while object data can be attached to any entity.

This is maybe the AutoCAD context, but DXF doesn't have the concept of "Object Data". You have to examine the DXF file to see what you are looking for e.g. with the ezdxf browse command.
